# How to add plots to a .rds graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

I have downloaded and created a plot of a .RDS file for my country. I am now attempting to plot the location of certain points from a separate dataset I have loaded into R (using their latitude and longitude).

I already understand how to plot these points using `ggmap` and `geom_point` but I want to use the output of my .RDS file plot as the background (because it contains district level borders that are not present in the Google Map sourced `ggmap` function).

I'm up for offering more clarity, feel free to ask!

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to show your background and points?

Comment: You may want to specify details about your input data---`.rds` only refers to a general object serialization format and may hold just about any R object. In addition, please clarify if you really *need* `ggmap`: If you are not at all interested in displaying map tiles from e.g. Google Maps, you should consider a different plotting method. If you are using data from [gadm.org](http://gadm.org/), you may find the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021701/) helpful.

Comment: I've downloaded the a spatial district-wise polygon file for Pakistan from http://www.gadm.org/country and plotted it using the technique mentioned here: (https://www.students.ncl.ac.uk/keith.newman/r/maps-in-r-using-gadm).

I now need to plot points onto this map using the existing database I have of these points' latitude and longitude. ggmap isn't a must, please suggest what would be the best means of achieving this.

Also, I would like to label these districts with their names if that's possible at all.